# How to grow new leaves on rubber plant after they fall off

Tags: indoors, pruning, leaves

I have a rubber plant that lost quite few leaves shortly after we got it.  We've got it back on track and are seeing some new chutes, but I'm wondering if there's a way to grow new leaves on the stems that lost most of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very rare for rubber plants to start new growth from the abcission area where a leaf was.  I have seen it in high light, high humidity areas but your most effective solution is cut the stem off near the base leaving one or two of the ridges on the stem where the leaves were attached above the soil line.

This may seem harsh but the plant will sprout out new growth after a few weeks and in six months your plant will look great and be shorter and more compact.